# Cannot get mappings to work

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-10

I have the following directory structure:

```
| SITES_FOLDER

    |___ WEBSITE1

        |___ WEBSITE_CFC

    |___ CFC_DIR
```

WEBSITE1 contains an Application.cfc and some pages. Then I have a component ShoppingCart.cfc inside the WEBSITE_CFC directory that is instantiated on session start using this code:

```
createObject("component","WEBSITE_CFC.ShoppingCart").Init() />
```

This works.

Now I move ShoppingCart.cfc to the CFC_DIR directory and change my instantiate code to:

```
createObject("component","CFC_DIR.ShoppingCart").Init() />
```

Obviously this does not work because ColdFusion searches for a "CFC_DIR" directory under the root directory "WEBSITE1" and doesn't find it.

I thought this problem would be solved by using **mappings** so I go to the CFIDE administrator. Server Settings > Mappings.

```
Logical path: "CFC_DIR"

Directory path: "C:\some\folders\SITES_FOLDER\CFC_DIR"
```

No luck. So then I tried in Application.cfc:

```
<cfset THIS.mappings["/CFC_DIR"] = "C:\some\folders\SITES_FOLDER\CFC_DIR" />
```

This did not work either!

**EDIT:**

Maybe I understand: if I try to create the CFC from a cfm template, it works.

The error comes up when I try to create it inside the *OnSessionStart* Application.cfc's method:

> Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface
>   exists. Message    Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface
>   C:\some\folders\SITES_FOLDER\WEBSITE1|WEBSITE_CFC\ShoppingCart.cfc.

In other words, it keeps looking for it in the wrong dir.

WHY?

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on what you mean when you say it doesn't work? Post the exact error message. I say this because based on what you tell us, it should all work, so there's something you're NOT telling us. We need to work out what that is.

Comment: Your server settings for the mapping should be working unless there is something else funky going on. What error do you get when you try to instantiate the object?

Comment: _"The error"_ - what error?

Comment: The Trusted Cache in cf admin. If you're changing the file to /CFC_DIR but it's still using /WEBSITE_CFC it sounds like the cache needs clearing.

Comment: it was the component cache, it was keeping the wrong absolute path cached. Thank you all. @PeterBoughton: add it as an answer, I will accept it and you'll grow up on reputation :)

Comment: Ok, have added answer with a few more relevant details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing the file to /CFC_DIR but it's still using /WEBSITE_CFC it sounds like the cache needs clearing.

#### Clear the Cache in CF Admin

Clearing the cache can be done manually in the ColdFusion Administrator. After login, the third item in "Server Settings" is "Caching". Scroll to the bottom of the page for buttons to clear the cache.

For development purposes you may want to consider disabling the various caching options on this page entirely - they can be useful for performance improvement on live servers, but are generally an unnecessary hindrance on your development machine.

#### Clear the Cache Programmatically

If you have an automated deployment, you don't want to have to login to the CF Admin on remote servers and press buttons. Fortunately, you can also [clear the cache programmatically](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/12/13/clearing_the_template_cache_programmatically):

```
<cfscript>
    createObject("Component", "cfide.adminapi.administrator")
        .login("**replace with admin password**");

    RuntimeService = createObject("component", "cfide.adminapi.runtime");

    // Clear whole cache:
    RuntimeService.clearTrustedCache();

    // Clear cache for individual files:
    RuntimeService.clearTrustedCache("/path/to/file1.cfm,/path/to/file2.cfm");

    // Clear component cache:
    RuntimeService.clearComponentCache();
</cfscript>
```

<sup>(Code adapted from [Charlie's blog entry](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2012/12/13/clearing_the_template_cache_programmatically).)</sup>

The API for the Admin Runtime component can be found at http://www.cfexecute.com/admin-api-documentation/runtime-cfc/

Comment: in my case it was "Components cache" thanks however you put me in the right direction

Comment: Yeah, it's not really clear where the delineation between the CF caches is - the description of component cache implies it's only the path to CFCs that gets cached, so shouldn't affect the content. \*shrug\* If in doubt, clear all caches. :)  I've updated the answer to include the clearComponentCache API method.

Comment: This post has been so much helpful for me. I was struggling and reading online for hours as to why my app won't initialize rest.
Thanks a ton @PeterBoughton